# Read XML file to datatables using c# asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, dataset

I want to read XML file and bulk copy to database

My xml is like :

```
<products>
    <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>product one</name>
      <subproducts>
        <subproduct>
           <color>Red</color>
           <stock>1</stock>
        </subproduct>
        <subproduct>
           <color>Green</color>
           <stock>2</stock>
        </subproduct>
      </subproducts>
      <images>
         <image>http://qwqeq.com</image>
         <image>http://asdasd.com</image>
      </images>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to get three datatables which are for products, subproducts and images and will try to bulk insert to the database.

How can i aschieve this ?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: yes i tried with Dataset ReadXml method but it gives me 6 datatables which i dont know how to use. Those are products product subproducts subproduct images image. I need three datatables that are relational to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have tried must be something like below,

```
DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
objDataSet.ReadXml("FilePath.xml");
```

It just groups the nodes and forms tables.

You need to do something which is explained well in the below link.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the XML into a stored procedure as XML parameter and shredd it there:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<products>
    <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>product one</name>
      <subproducts>
        <subproduct>
           <color>Red</color>
           <stock>1</stock>
        </subproduct>
        <subproduct>
           <color>Green</color>
           <stock>2</stock>
        </subproduct>
      </subproducts>
      <images>
         <image>http://qwqeq.com</image>
         <image>http://asdasd.com</image>
      </images>
    </product>
</products>';

SELECT p.value(N'id[1]',N'int') AS productID
      ,p.value(N'name[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS productName
      ,sp.value(N'color[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS subproductColor
      ,sp.value(N'stock[1]','int') AS subproductStock
      ,img.value(N'image[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS imageURL
--INTO #tmpTbl
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/products/product') AS A(p)
OUTER APPLY p.nodes(N'subproducts/subproduct') AS B(sp)
OUTER APPLY p.nodes(N'images') AS C(img)
```

The result

```
productID   productName   subproductColor   subproductStock imageURL
1           product one   Red               1               http://qwqeq.com
1           product one   Green             2               http://qwqeq.com
```

Use `SELECT ... INTO #tmpTbl` to write the result into a staging table. Then use `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM #tmpTbl` to retrieve the values for your insertion into the final structure.